# FFMPEG video encoded by android app doesn't scale properly on the website

Tags: android, html, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to creat e an app that records a video on phone and uploads it to the website. I'm using a FFMPEG library to encode the video to be streamed on the web. The command I'm using for encoding is below:

```
-y i inputPath -vf scale=640:480,transpose=1 -strict experimental -s 360x640 -r 25 -vcodec mpeg4 -b 1000k ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 destinationPath
```

The video is encoded fine but when I try to play it on the website, it's stretched vertically and goes off the screen. I'm using html5 player to play it on the web. Here's what the video looks like

[image]

The video uploaded from the website is encoded using libx264 codec and it plays fine. However the library I'm using to encode on the android app doesn't support libx264. I'm not sure if it's the incorrect aspect ratio that's messing up the playback or something else. I've set the aspet ratio to `640:480` but that hasn't fixed things.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is scaling the video twice. First is the scale filter, and the second is the `-s` option. Remove one of these. Also, the scale filter adjusts the aspect ratio. That can be countered with a `setsar` filter.

So,

```
-y -i inputPath -vf scale=640:480,setsar=1,transpose=1 -strict experimental -r 25 -vcodec mpeg4 -b 1000k ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 destinationPath
```